# Scripts works perfect when i run it manually, but on crontab something is wrong

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, shell, cron

I am new on writing Unix shell scripts. I have written a script which include Oracle Database sql codes. As you see below, it writes outout of sql codes on text files and i want to send these outputs by mail.
It works very well when i run it manually. But when on crontab it does not do it as i want. Sql codes work very well, text files are updated, it sends mail but values are blank in mail. 
I read some other problems, i wrote all paths but i could not find the problem. I hope you can find the solution.
Thank you, best regards

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
./home/partner/.profile
NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P9
ORACLE_BASE=/oracle
ORACLE_SID=----------------
ORACLE_HOME=-------------
USER=------------
PASSWD=--------------
SCRIPTPATH=/home/path-to/scripts/
spoolfile=$SCRIPTPATH/textfile1.txt
spoolfile2=$SCRIPTPATH/textfile2.txt
export NLS_LANG ORACLE_BASE ORACLE_SID  ORACLE_HOME

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus $USER/$PASSWD<<EOF
@$SCRIPTPATH/code1.sql $spoolfile
exit;
EOF

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus $USER/$PASSWD<<EOF
@$SCRIPTPATH/code2.sql $spoolfile2
exit;
EOF

value1=`/usr/bin/cat textfile1.txt`
value2=`/usr/bin/cat textfile2.txt`

if [[ -s $spoolfile ]] ; then
echo "mail1 "$value1 "text "$value2 | mailx -s "subject" mymail@abc.com
else
echo "mail2" | mailx -s "subject" mymail@abc.com 
fi
```

Comment: Can you edit your crontab to send the output to a log find `...>>log.txt` and upload that?

Comment: It may be a permission problem also if you are running as the user for cron.

Comment: A common problem comes from the setting of the environment variables when the crontab is executed. Make sure to set the environment variables inside the script called by crontab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
spoolfile=$SCRIPTPATH/textfile1.txt
spoolfile2=$SCRIPTPATH/textfile2.txt
```

and then later

```
value1=`/usr/bin/cat textfile1.txt`
value2=`/usr/bin/cat textfile2.txt`
```

looks like the textfiles are saved in one place and read from another.